# Silverlight ListBox ItemTemplate: Make certain elements visible when item is selected

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

In a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight application, I have this ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs}" >                        
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Begin, Converter={StaticResource TimeOfDayConverter}}" Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="46" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="30" />
                </StackPanel>
               <TextBlock x:Name="txtDescription" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="56,0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I need to have the TextBlock named `txtDescription` be collapsed by default, but set it to visible when the item is selected. How can I do that (preferably in XAML) ?

Comment: You can add a simple storyboard on the ListBoxItem that toggles the Visibility of the TextBlock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the VisualStateManager to change what is visible based on the SelectionState.

An example of doing similar operations based on selection (but not on the phone) can be found at http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/180002/405838.aspx

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578128/list-box-with-multiple-data-template-style-for-selected-item