# List box with multiple data template - style for selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox, windows-phone

I have List Box with 2 data template, i have a ItemContainerStyle for list box as well which will highlight the selected item in the list box.

Below is my code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
            <Border  

                    Margin="0,2,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid> items ...</Grid>
           </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Datatemplate with Convertor:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewDataTemplate">
            <Border  
                    Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor}}"
                    Margin="0,2,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid> items ...</Grid>
           </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have a button in the application bar on click on that button i am programatically setting the `NewDataTemplate which will change 2 item colors  to green in the list box`.

List box item selector style:

```
<Style x:Key="ListItemSelectorStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="ListBoxItem" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ListItemBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#c9ebf2" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ListItemBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#c9ebf2" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ListItemBorder" 
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#e3e8f0">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This will apply the style when we select the item.

Now this style works good on my DefaultDataTemplate when i click on the item in the list box that means the item gets highlighted, but when the NewDataTemplate is set the  style is not showing at all.

How can i fix this ?

Note : I am working on Windows Phone 8 application.

**EDIT 1**

```
public class BackgroundConvertor: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = null;

            if (value != null)
            {
                MyObject obj = value as MyObject ;
                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    if (obj.IsCorrect == 1 && parameter.ToString() == "0")
                    {
                        solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)201, (byte)235, (byte)242)); //blue color                                                       
                    }
                    else if (obj.IsCorrect == 1 && parameter.ToString() == "1")  
                    {
                        solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)201, (byte)242, (byte)169));//green color                                                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)227, (byte)232, (byte)240));//Grey color.
                    }
                }
                else if (obj.IsCorrect == 1)
                {
                    solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)201, (byte)242, (byte)169));//green color  
                }

                else
                {
                    solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)227, (byte)232, (byte)240));//Grey color.
                }
            }
            return solidColorBrush;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

This is my MyObject class:

```
public class MyObject 
    {
private byte isCorrect;
        public byte IsCorrect
        {
            get { return isCorrect; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.isCorrect)
                {
                    isCorrect = value;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove `Background="{Binding...` from the NewDataTemplate? Also post code of your converter and also code of the item class.

Comment: Yes if i remove the `Background ="{Binding...` from the NewDataTemplate the `ListItemSelectorStyle` works fine.But i need that converter because i need to highlight 2 items among 4 items in the list box, i will share my converter code

Comment: For example, your item has `.IsCorrect == 1` and is displayed as green. What should happen if you click the item? What happens now?

Comment: @vorrtex if i click the item the style color i.e., `<VisualState x:Name="Selected">` will be applied to it

Comment: Is it applied now? Do you want that the `Selected` state is applied? Or you rather want that it is not applied?

Comment: @vorrtex i want the selected state to be applied,on select and again on deselect it should be removed

Comment: You can try to remove `Background ="{Binding` from your new data template. Andchange ListBoxItem so, I added a rectangle before the border and changed background color to transparent: `<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor}}" />
<Border x:Name="ListItemBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
...`

Comment: @vorrtex Ok i will try that, give me 2 mins

Comment: I tried that it gives me error visual tree can be set only once

Comment: Add a `<Grid></Grid>` control outside both elements so that 2 elements are inside 1 grid.

Comment: @vorrtex i tried that as well its still the same.

Comment: What's the same? This error is because your border has 2 children, it should have only 1 child, so wrapping them into 1 grid will definitely solve this error, here is another proof http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621454/visualtree-is-set-more-than-once

Comment: @vorrtex No i meant to say that, i dont have any error,but its not working as expected, which i have told in my question

Comment: Anyway you should try to change your ListBoxItem template so that it has 2 `Rectangle` elements as in the temlate from this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx. Then you could add the 3rd rectangle before them with a binding to your background. This is the only way I know how to make your selection work.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issue with your 2nd `DataTemplate`.

In Below Code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewDataTemplate">
    <Border  
            Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor}}"
            Margin="0,2,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid> items ...</Grid>
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

In above code look at :

`Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor}}"`

1. You are not providing any path. Thus your converter will not get any input value.
2. Also, you should specify the parameters in above binding.

**Take a look at below example:**

First in your ViewModel declare a property like below :

```
private MyObject myBackground;
public MyObject MyBackground
{
    get
    {
        return myBackground;
    }
    set
    {
        myBackground = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyBackground");
    }
}
```

Fill the values in MyBackground before changing the DataTemplate or in the Constructor of your ViewModel.

In your DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewDataTemplate">
    <Border  
            Background="{Binding Path=MyBackground, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor} 
                                 ConverterParameter='1'}" />
            Margin="0,2,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid> items ...</Grid>
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

The converter you specified in above code should be used here as well.

**Note:** The above example code is not tested. If there are any errors, then please try to solve it. And if you have any problems please feel free to ask.

**Update:**

You don't need to make any changes to your `Answer` Class.

In your ViewModel just declare a property like below:

```
private Answer myBackground;
public Answer MyBackground
{
    get
    {
        return myBackground;
    }
    set
    {
        myBackground = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyBackground");
    }
}
```

Use the XAML that I mentioned previously in my Answer.

Make changes to your converter like below code:

```
public class BackgroundConvertor: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = null;

        if (value != null)
        {
            Answer answer = (Answer)value ;
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                if (answer.IsCorrect == 1 && parameter.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)201, (byte)235, (byte)242)); //blue color                                                       
                }
                else if (answer.IsCorrect == 1 && parameter.ToString() == "1")  
                {
                    solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)201, (byte)242, (byte)169));//green color                                                        
                }
                else
                {
                    solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)227, (byte)232, (byte)240));//Grey color.
                }
            }
            else if (answer.IsCorrect == 1)
            {
                solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)201, (byte)242, (byte)169));//green color  
            }

            else
            {
                solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb((byte)255, (byte)227, (byte)232, (byte)240));//Grey color.
            }
        }
        return solidColorBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit, and help me to my modify my class to what you have suggested to add myBackground

Comment: Can we please go into some chat room,can you please invite me

Comment: can you please join here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50266/solving-problem