# Button click highlight list box item WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a list box with 4 items say A,B,C and D.

I have a button in the application bar,onclick of that button i need to highlight or change the background color of the list item A and B to Green.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in XAML,

Add the following lines inside your  tag

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

Comment: could two items be selected at a time?

Comment: He wants to change items color on button click, not on listbox event

Comment: Button click and the event i added will have the same effect!

Comment: I am working on windows phone 8 application, will the above code works for that ?

Comment: Please check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578128/list-box-with-multiple-data-template-style-for-selected-item

Comment: I have tried the above code in my XAMl file it says x:Static is not found in silverlight project

Comment: @Sajeetharan Application Bar Icon has only click event.

Comment: @user2056563 include this namespace in xaml xmlns:A="clr-namespace:x"

Comment: post your xaml, i wil modify and post